# Related rates clock problem

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The clock on the wall at the FedEx office has an hour hand that's 4 cm long and a minute hand that's 8 cm long. At exactly 2:00, at what rate, in centimeters per minute, is the distance between the tips of the two hands changing?

I know that because they're talking about two hands of a clock and the distance between them, I can start the problem with the Cosine Law, but I don't know how to use this:

80-64cos(theta)=d^2

To get further.

Comment: Not sure the angle between the two is the best dependent variable to use.  I'd suggest using the two angles (one for each hand).  After all, we know how those variables depend on time.

Answer (score 2):

**PARTIAL SOLUTION:** Let the origin be the center of the clock. Then the parametric coordinates for the tip of the long hand are
$$(8\cos 60t,8\sin 60t)$$
where $t$ is in hours. Then the tip of the short hand is
$$(4\cos t,4\sin t)$$
and so the distance is
$$d(t)=\sqrt{(8\cos 60t-4\cos t)^2+(8\sin 60t-4\sin t)^2}$$

There you go - I've set you up with a function. Now can you differentiate it?